# Oozie Job getting Suspended and not reaching YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to start a Oozie Shell Action Job via cli as:
`oozie job -config jobprops/jos.prioperties -run`

The Job Starts, it gives me a **unique Id** and I can see Job in Oozie UI.

However, Yarn Console shows **no** submitted jobs and on checking log in oozie I get following message:

`Error starting action [folder-structure].

ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009]

Message [JA009: Permission denied: user=vikas.r, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:257)`.

The job finally goes to **SUSPENDED** state.
Why is job trying to access "/" ?  How could it be resolved ?

I am running under unix user vikas.r, with all folders in hdfs at /user/vikas.r

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite straightforward. Your oozie job is trying to write something to / as vikas.r user, which lacks permissions to do so.